# Extending regular React components with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

The [docs for styled-components show](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#styled) its default `styled` export accepts a single argument:

> `styled`
>
> This is the default export. This is a low-level factory we use to create the `styled.tagname` helper methods.
>
> Arguments
>
> `component` / `tagname`
>
> Description
>
> Either a *valid react component* or a tagname like `'div'`.

I've emphasized *"valid react component"* here because they explicitly aren't saying this has to be a React component *created by* `styled`, although traditionally that *is* how this is used (as well as [documented under their *Extending Styled* section](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles)). An example of this is shown below:

```js
const RedBox = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
`;

// Traditionally, the argument you pass to `styled` is
// a react element *created by a previous `styled` call*
const BlueBox = styled(RedBox)`
  color: blue;
`;

function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RedBox>I am a red box</RedBox>
      <BlueBox>I am a blue box</BlueBox>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is@17.0.1/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@5.2.1/dist/styled-components.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Nothing unsurprising with the above.

However, my question is **what if you pass a *non* styled component as the argument to the `styled` call?** Shouldn't that returned element also get the styles applied?

Consider the following simple example:

```js
// Create two simple components, one functional, one class-based
const BoxFunctional = (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>;
class BoxClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}

// Here, I pass a functional React Component to `styled`
const RedBoxFunctional = styled(BoxFunctional)`
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;
// Again, passing another regular React component, this time a class component
const RedBoxClass = styled(BoxClass)`
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>The below two Boxes are regular react elements:</p>
      <BoxFunctional>I am a functional box</BoxFunctional>
      <BoxClass>I am a class box</BoxClass>
      <hr />
      <p>The below two boxes <em>should</em> be styled:</p>
      <RedBoxFunctional>I am a functional red box</RedBoxFunctional>
      <RedBoxClass>I am a class red box</RedBoxClass>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-is@17.0.1/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@5.2.1/dist/styled-components.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Running the above snippet you can see that the `styled` components are **not** styled, despite them extending a "valid" react component.

Is there something I'm missing? Are the docs just incorrect? Can `styled` only apply styles to an existing react component that is made by a previous `styled` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know where the confusion lies, you can pass any React component to the `styled` Higher Order Component.

The issue you have is that you aren't trying to style the `BoxFunctional` or `BoxClass` components, but rather you are trying to style the JSX they render. You just need to proxy the `className` prop through to what each renders.

[Styling any Component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)

> The `styled` method works perfectly on all of your own or any
> third-party component, as long as they attach the passed `className`
> prop to a DOM element.

```
const BoxFunctional = (props) => (
  <div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>
);

class BoxClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className={this.props.className}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit extending-regular-react-components-with-styled-components]

[image]

Comment: _"as long as they attach the passed `className` prop to a DOM element"_ is what I was missing. Thanks!